# Get the bucket url of Cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I have a set of `yaml` templates (one root template and several childs) to create a root stack and nested stacks in the top level of an S3 bucket. It looks like:

```
my-cf-templates-bucket (S3 bucket)
├ root.yaml
├ child1.yaml
├ child2.yaml
├ ...
└ childN.yaml
```

In order to supply the `TemplateURL` of the child templates, currently I make use of a parameter `TemplateS3Bucket` for the bucket URL:

```
Parameters:
  TemplateS3Bucket:
    Description: The bucket url for templates
    Type: String
    Default: https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/my-cf-templates-bucket
Resources:
  ChildStack1:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: !Join ["/", [ !Ref TemplateS3Bucket, "child1.yaml"]]
      Parameters:
        ProjectName: !Ref ProjectName
  ChildStack1:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: !Join ["/", [ !Ref TemplateS3Bucket, "child2.yaml"]]
      Parameters:
        ProjectName: !Ref ProjectName
  # ...
  ChildStackN:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: !Join ["/", [ !Ref TemplateS3Bucket, "childN.yaml"]]
      Parameters:
        ProjectName: !Ref ProjectName
```

**The question is:**

Is there a way (`!GetAtt` etc.) to get the **bucket URL** of the S3 root template through which I create a stack in AWS CloudFormation console (not aws-cli).

Having such a way, I could intrinsically have the bucket url for the child templates and neither need to add them as overrideable parameters nor repeat the full bucket url for all the `templateURL` properties of the child stacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way that I'm aware of. Passing the S3 bucket of the templates as a parameters seems to be the the standard/most common way of doing things.